# How to get the managed object from selected annotation

Tags: core-data, annotations, mkmapview, cllocationmanager

I have a model: Event, I have loaded the annotation view to the mapview, but how do I get the event managed object from the selected annotation, so I can push a view controller to display event's info. The viewForAnnotation part:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{


    if([annotation class] == MKUserLocation.class) {
        //userLocation = annotation;
        return nil;
    }

    REVClusterPin *pin = (REVClusterPin *)annotation;

    MKAnnotationView *annView;

        annView = [aMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"pin"];

        if( !annView )
            annView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                    reuseIdentifier:@"pin"];

        annView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pinpoint.png"];
        annView.canShowCallout = YES;
        UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        [rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(displayViewController:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
        annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-6.0, 0.0);
    }
    return annView;
}
```

and the rightCalloutAccessoryView displayViewController part :

```
- (void)displayViewController:(id)sender
{
    Annotation *annotation = [self.mapView selectedAnnotations][0];
    EventsViewController *eventsVC = [[EventsViewController alloc] init];
    eventsVC.event = ???
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:eventsVC animated:YES];
}
```

How to get the managed object from Annotation *annotation = [self.mapView selectedAnnotations][0] ? If I declare a event in Annotation, then what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class Annotation is your own is it not? Does it contain a property for holding the `event`? If not then it should.

If you remove the custom selector you've assigned to rightButton and you've set the delegates correctly then you should get a call to this function

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)map annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    REVClusterPin *annotation = (REVClusterPin *)view.annotation;
    EventsViewController *eventsVC = [[EventsViewController alloc] init];
    eventsVC.event = annotation.event;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:eventsVC animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: the Annotation class is my own. So, I should declare a event object in the Annotation class? But it crashed. What else should I do?

Comment: Oh, I figured it out. I declare a event property in the REVClusterPin and it wokred. Thanks anyway. I prefer the selector way.

Comment: The selector way you are using seems a bit disconnected because it relies on asking the map for the selected annotations and assuming only one is selected, or that the first of the array is the one you want. The delegate method actually gives you the annotation view that was picked and from that you get the correct annotation. I've modified my answer to use your REVClusterPin class.

Comment: I see. I will use the delegate then. Thanks.